# MongoDB: stuck mongod.lock file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I ran db.fsyncLock() command and then the server was restarted without me running  db.fsyncUnlock().
After the restart, mongo does not start with the error

> 2020-04-17T10:13:59.693+0300 Error: couldn't connect to server
>   127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146

What should I do? Can I just delete the lock file?

Thanks a lot!

Below are the logs and the ls of the directory

```
1583  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
 1584  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
 1585  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
 1586  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
 1587  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
 1588  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
 1589  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
 1590  2020-04-17T08:08:02.481+0300 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
 1591  2020-04-17T08:08:02.486+0300 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
 1592  2020-04-17T08:08:02.486+0300 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
 1593  ~$ ls -l /var/lib/mongodb
 1594  total 294932
 1595  -rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  67108864 Apr 16 21:57 ctf.0
 1596  -rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 134217728 Apr 16 21:57 ctf.1
 1597  -rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  16777216 Apr 16 21:56 ctf.ns
 1598  drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb      4096 Apr 16 22:04 journal
 1599  -rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  67108864 Feb 26 04:47 local.0
 1600  -rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  16777216 Feb 26 04:47 local.ns
 1601  -rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb         0 Apr 17 08:31 mongod.lock
```

Comment: That log file shows the database server stopped about 2 hours before you tried to connect.  Has it restarted since then?

Comment: No, it can't. As I wrote, it fails with the error above

Comment: The "couldn't connect" error is from something trying to connect to the database node using the local host address. Does attempting to start the mongod produce any error?